# How to setup CleanBrowsing app properly?

Tags: applications, device-administrator, private-dns

I installed the CleanBrowsing app on my Redmi 9a (Android 10) phone and it asks for accessibility permission. I give that permission, but when I activate the family filter, it goes to Private DNS on Settings and asks me to save it, and then it does nothing, just goes back to the family filter option again. It should ask me for device admin permission but it doesn't.
On my other Samsung (Android 12) phone, this app works very well.

Comment: Could you clarify the issue, like is the problem with setting the Private DNS, or it doesn't ask for device admin permission? For Private DNS, I'd assume it's possible to manually set using [the official documentation](https://cleanbrowsing.org/guides/android/).

Comment: I mean,when i press activate family filter it show me directly the setting with Private Dns and to aave it,i press save and then it does nothing when after that it should direct me to the device admin option.Idk if you understand?!

Comment: I can't use the Playstore version of the app because you can easyly uninstall it that why i need the device admin permission and with this web version i can't set it